# parallel request using JSR223 Sampler (Jmeter)

Tags: ajax, api, parallel-processing, jmeter

I'm trying to use the following code (by Dmitri) in `JMeter 3.0`, however, I am unsuccessful in running it. my goal is to **simulate parallel API calls**.

Any idea why its failing? code:

```
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors; // necessary imports


List<String> urls = new ArrayList<String>(); // initialize array of URLs
Collections.addAll(urls,args); // read URLs from "Parameters" input and add them to array
ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(urls.size()); // initialize pool of Future Tasks with number of threads equal to size of URLs provided
for (String url : urls) { // for each URL from list
   final String currentURL = url;
   pool.submit(new Runnable() { // Sumbit a new thread which will execute GET request

       @Override
       public void run() {
           try {
               HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(); // Use Apache Commons HTTPClient to perform GET request
  HttpGet get = new HttpGet(currentURL);
     HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
EntityUtils.consume(entity);
           } catch (Exception ex) {
               ex.printStackTrace();
           }

       }
   });
}
pool.shutdown(); // shut down thread pool
```

**Error thrown is (i did use 2 example hosts in parameter field jsr223 sampler):**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host is null
        at org.apache.http.util.Asserts.notNull(Asserts.java:52)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpRoutePlanner.determineRoute(DefaultHttpRoutePlanner.java:99)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.determineRoute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:763)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:382)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:884)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:107)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
        at org.apache.http.client.HttpClient$execute.call(Unknown Source)
        at Script3$1.run(Script3.groovy:26)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code looks ok

1. Make sure you have `groovy` selected in the "Language" dropdown
2. Make sure you provide at least 1 URL in "Parameters" section (including protocol, `http` or `https`). If you use > 1 url - separate them by spaces, i.e.

   ```
   http://url1/path http://url2/path2
   ```

Demo:

[image: JSR223 AJAX Demo]

Source: [How to Load Test AJAX/XHR Enabled Sites With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-ajaxxhr-enabled-sites-jmeter)

Comment: Did exactly this way. Still keep getting the same error. Do you have a testplan somewhere which i can download with working code?

Comment: do you know if it is possible to send HTTP Headers along  with these requests? i have a bearer (api access token) which i also need to pass in the header of the get request.

Comment: It is. Just add the next line: `get.addHeader("Header-Name","Header-Value");` after `HttpGet get = new HttpGet(currentURL);`

Comment: I included a Transaction controller with Create Parent Sample on. However, not getting the response time. Do i need additional code?

Comment: Theoretically no. It's hard to say without seeing your test plan

Comment: I am getting valid responses from the api calls though.. but JSR sample response times are not similar to 'normal' http sample response times (like only a fraction of it)

Answer (score 0):

@DMC try adding:

`pool.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
after pool.shurdown();`

it will give you the proper response time