# Adding Cookie from previous sampler in JSR223 Sampler Jmeter

Tags: java, cookies, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jsr223

I am trying to execute ajax calls from JSR223 Sampler like in [parallel request using JSR223 Sampler (Jmeter)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38696329/parallel-request-using-jsr223-sampler-jmeter).

I am able to get a response from ajax calls that don't need login auth cookie.
However, not getting a response from ajax calls that need auth cookie generated by the login.

I have added login http call before JSR223 sampler but cookie is not getting passed in request. Tried by adding code:

```
HTTPSamplerProxy previousSampler = ctx.getPreviousSampler();
CookieManager cookieManager = previousSampler.getCookieManager();
HTTPSampleResult previousResult = (HTTPSampleResult)ctx.getPreviousResult();
log.info("Cookie Count is : "+ cookieManager.getCookieCount());
```

It throws below exception:

> 2017-11-28 10:44:51,195 ERROR o.a.j.p.j.s.JSR223Sampler: Problem in
>   JSR223 script JSR223 Sampler, message: javax.script.ScriptException:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getCookieCount()
>   on null object javax.script.ScriptException:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getCookieCount()
>   on null object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you're getting indicates that you don't have [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) added/enabled.

---

As an alternative to Groovy scripting you can use "normal" JMeter [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers which naturally support cookies, cache, headers, authorization, etc.

In order to be able to execute them in AJAX-like parallel manner put the samplers under [Parallel Controller](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/parallel/Parallel.md#parallel-controller). You can install the Parallel Controller using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

[image: JMeter Plugins Manager Parallel Controller]

Comment: Thanks in advance. Please let me know how to add post request with body data in this sampler?

Comment: Apologies, I am able to add post request as well. Thanks a lot

Comment: Dmitri, Sampler under parallel controller is showing the response time more than 3-4 times as compare to when the same sampler executed outside parallel controller. Is parallel controller adding any hidden think time here?

Answer (score 0):

Check that you added CookieManager in your test pkan.

Also use a JSR223 Pre Processor instead of a JsR223 Sampler.

Answer (score 0):

As said before, do you have a HTTP cookie manager ? 
And this is the code to add a cookie into the cookie manager

```
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Cookie;

try {
    String params = vars.get("getCookieValue");
    ctx.getCurrentSampler().getCookieManager().add(new Cookie("COOKIENAME", params, "domain", "/url", true, Long.MAX_VALUE));
}
catch (Throwable ex) {
    log.error("Error in Beanshell", ex);
    throw ex;
}
```